# Quais as diferenças entre BLOC x Cubit?

Tags: flutter, dart

BLOC e Cubit fazem parte do mesmo pacote ([bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)) e utilizam o mesmo padrão *(BLoC - Design Pattern Business Logic Component)* que ajuda a separar a camada de apresentação da regra de negócio.

Quais são as diferenças entre os dois modelos e quais as vantagens de cada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A principal diferença entre BLoC e Cubit, é que o BLoC requer a implementação de eventos (**Events**) que serão responsáveis por alterar os seus estados (**States**). Um Cubit é uma versão mais leve do BLoC, pois trabalha apenas com estados e métodos internos que irão alterar diretamente a estes estados.

Nos Widgets que consomem um BLoC, por exemplo o BlocBuilder, você pode trocar um BLoC por um Cubit com facilidade, dado que o BLoC é internamente construído através de um Cubit e estes Widgets observam apenas o estado do objeto.

A vantagem de usar um Cubit é que para casos de uso mais simples, você tem a facilidade de não precisar declarar diferentes eventos e principalmente fazer o mapeamento destes eventos para os estados internos do objeto, o que melhora a legibilidade e reduz a quantidade de código para a execução da tarefa.

Exemplo de BLoC simples que implementa um contador:

```
/// Evento a ser processado por [CounterBloc].
enum CounterEvent {
  /// Notifica o Bloc a incrementar seu estado.
  increment,

  /// Notifica o Bloc a fazer um decremento em seu estado.
  decrement
}

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  CounterBloc() : super(0);

  //Método que mapeia Eventos adicionados ao Bloc para novos Estados
  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.decrement:
        yield state - 1;
        break;
      case CounterEvent.increment:
        yield state + 1;
        break;
      default:
        addError(Exception('unsupported event'));
    }
  }
}
```

Cubit que implementa o mesmo comportamento, sem a necessidade de declarar e mapear eventos para estados:

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}
```

Comment: Boa resposta, você diz que: `"você pode trocar trocar um BLoC por um Cubit com facilidade"` dá a entender que se eu tiver um código com BLoC (e caso queira simplificar com Cubit) posso implementar Cubit facilmente, é realmente isso? Poderia exemplificar na resposta?

Comment: Obrigado rubStackOverflow, atualizei a resposta para demonstrar a ideia.